# installing ricoh SP 201N printer driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, printer

I want to install ricoh SP 201 N driver on windows 10.
I downloaded here http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re2/model/sp201n/sp201n.htm?lang=es the driver for windows 10 64 bits (i guess the one in my laptop is not 32 bits right ?).
Then I unzip, follow the instructions from "readme" files.
Everything goes well, but when it comes in the end to "print a test page", nothing happens... And the printer doesn't work..

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Printing is currently severely broken on Windows 10. This may or may not affect you.

Comment: Well the strange thing is that with another computer under win10 I had been able to install this same driver a few months ago. So I don't think the problem comes from the OS.

Comment: Is the printer connected to your computer via USB or is it shared on the network with its own IP address? Have you checked the cables to make sure they're not damaged, and that they are properly connected to the devices and network (as appropriate)?

Comment: By “currently” I mean “right now”. Updates this month (March 2021) [broke printing in certain circumstances](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-warns-of-more-printing-issues-caused-by-march-updates/).

Comment: @Jeff : the printer is USB, and is the only one. The USB cable is ok, as well as the connection with computer.

Comment: The current Microsoft printing disaster - they do seem to have released a patch, at least to their enterprise customers - only affects V3 print drivers. If your current Ricoh driver is V4, it doesn't affect you. If it's V3, see if you can get a V4 driver, and if not, try installing a V4 driver for either generic/text or something compatible with the printer - probably an HP or PostScript driver.

Comment: How can I check if the driver is V3 or V4 ?